# Read certain files in a specific directory in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io

How do I read all the files *with a specific extension* from a certain directory in MATLAB, and take the name of each file (without its extension) and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function outNames = GetNames()
dirList = dir('c:');
names = {dirList.name};
outNames = {};
for i=1:numel(names)
    name = names{i};
    if ~isequal(name,'.') && ~isequal(name,'..')
        [~,name] = fileparts(names{i});
        outNames{end+1} = name;
    end
end    
end
```

Comment: an errer accured while trying this code::: parses error {~} matlab syntax error

Comment: Oww.. I am using a newer Matlab than you. Just replace the "~" with "unused" string.

Comment: but u have to add the extention u want to the second line::

dirList = dir('c:\\*.ext');

Comment: Just take {dirList.ext} and check them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dir` command to get the directory contents, and the `fileparts` function to strip the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify the answer even more:

```
%# list all .txt files in a folder, and get filenames without extensions
BASE_DIR = 'C:\path\to\directory';
files = dir( fullfile(BASE_DIR,'*.txt') );
[~,files] = cellfun(@fileparts, {files.name}, 'UniformOutput',false)
```

Comment: In this way you will get the '.' and the '..', which is obviously something you don't want

Comment: @Andrey: actually it won't, if you look closely this will only return files names with a `.txt` extension